# out of memory error while decoding the image with sample size after decoding it within bounds

Tags: android

I am beginner in android. While decoding the images ( of size 1600x1200 ) from SD card one by one i am getting the below error. After decoding the bitmap i have to apply the animation for the imageview to play the image like slide show in full screen. i am using the below calculation for getting samplesize after decoding the bitmap in bounds.

```
while (true) {
    if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_WIDTH || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_HEIGHT )
        break;
    width_tmp /= 2;
    height_tmp /= 2;
    scale *= 2;
}
```

Can anyone please help me to solve this issue.

```
Error:
11-09 13:39:15.100: E/DhcpStateMachine(424): DHCP failed on wlan0: Timed out waiting for DHCP to finish
11-09 13:39:15.300: E/WifiStateMachine(424): IP configuration failed
11-09 13:39:32.840: E/dalvikvm-heap(2511): Out of memory on a 20155408-byte allocation.
11-09 13:39:32.870: E/AndroidRuntime(2511): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
11-09 13:39:32.870: E/AndroidRuntime(2511): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
11-09 13:39:32.870: E/AndroidRuntime(2511):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
11-09 13:39:32.870: E/AndroidRuntime(2511):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
11-09 13:39:32.870: E/AndroidRuntime(2511):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
11-09 13:39:32.870: E/AndroidRuntime(2511):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
11-09 13:39:32.870: E/AndroidRuntime(2511):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
11-09 13:39:32.870: E/AndroidRuntime(2511):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
11-09 13:39:32.870: E/AndroidRuntime(2511):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
11-09 13:39:32.870: E/AndroidRuntime(2511):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
11-09 13:39:32.870: E/AndroidRuntime(2511):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
11-09 13:39:32.870: E/AndroidRuntime(2511): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
11-09 13:39:32.870: E/AndroidRuntime(2511):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
11-09 13:39:32.870: E/AndroidRuntime(2511):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:527)
11-09 13:39:32.870: E/AndroidRuntime(2511):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:301)
11-09 13:39:32.870: E/AndroidRuntime(2511):     at com.example.testproject1.Imgloader.loadImageFromSDCard(Imgloader.java:60)
11-09 13:39:32.870: E/AndroidRuntime(2511):     at com.example.testproject1.Imgloader.access$0(Imgloader.java:50)
11-09 13:39:32.870: E/AndroidRuntime(2511):     at com.example.testproject1.Imgloader$SDLoadImageTask.doInBackground(Imgloader.java:177)
11-09 13:39:32.870: E/AndroidRuntime(2511):     at com.example.testproject1.Imgloader$SDLoadImageTask.doInBackground(Imgloader.java:1)
11-09 13:39:32.870: E/AndroidRuntime(2511):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
11-09 13:39:32.870: E/AndroidRuntime(2511):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
11-09 13:39:32.870: E/AndroidRuntime(2511):     ... 5 more
11-09 13:39:32.970: E/dalvikvm-heap(2511): Out of memory on a 20155408-byte allocation.
11-09 13:39:46.530: E/DhcpStateMachine(424): DHCP failed on wlan0: Timed out waiting for DHCP to finish
11-09 13:39:46.749: E/WifiStateMachine(424): IP configuration failed
11-09 13:40:18.180: E/DhcpStateMachine(424): DHCP failed on wlan0: Timed out waiting for DHCP to finish
11-09 13:40:18.399: E/WifiStateMachine(424): IP configuration failed
11-09 13:40:18.399: E/WifiStateMachine(424): Failed 10 times, Disabling 3
```

Comment: you forgot to post the code.

Comment: sorry, now i have added the code.

Comment: not enough code for anyone to help you. But considering my experience trying to deal with those I'll have a guess: your images are way too big, try dealing with smaller ones.

Comment: The `Out of memory on a 20155408-byte allocation` @ Imgloader.java:60 means that you try to load a huge (~5 Megapixel) image that needs 20MB. That's more than a 1600x1200 image would use (~7MB) so there is something wrong

Comment: Agree with zapl, a 1600x1200 image would use only about 8 MB of memory (still a lot, but not 20MB). Seems like there's something else wrong. You should post all of the code that relates to how you are loading and resampling the images.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following method to scale an image based on an empirically determined maximum memory size `max_size` which in my purposes is 2,000,000.

```
private Bitmap decodeUri(Uri selectedImage) throws FileNotFoundException {

    InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(
            selectedImage);
    UriHelper uriHelper = new UriHelper(this);
    mSaveFilenameRoot = uriHelper.getFilenameRoot(selectedImage);

    // Decode image size
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, o);
    try {
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Find the correct scale value. A power of 2 is best (fastest)
    // however using the scaling that maximizes the size of the image.
    int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
    int scale = 1;

    // maximum size due to heap size limitations
            // Bytes required based on width x height x 4 bytes per pixel
    int max_size = 2000000;
    while (true) {
        if (((width_tmp / scale) * (height_tmp / scale) * 4) < max_size)
            break;
        scale++;
    }

    // Decode the image at the appropriate scale
    inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
    o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inSampleSize = scale;
    o.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
    Bitmap tmpBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, o);
    try {
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return tmpBitmap;
}
```

Comment: Just a note: `Bitmap.Config.RGB_565` should use only 2 byte per pixel (5 + 6 + 5 bit), but `inPreferredConfig` makes no guarantees about the actual returned pixel format so it could be 4 byte.

Comment: @zapl - agree with your comment.  Was originally using `Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888` and changed to `Bitmap.Config.RGB_565` at some point (was originally written over a year ago).  Concept should still work.

Answer (score 1):

Since you havent mentioned the SDK version that you can targeting, the best performance can be obtained through *Render Script*

A sample of its usage can also be found at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html